Appium2 + iOS app : Appium inspector is not loading to inspect elements for iOS after upgrading to macOS Sequoia
Background : I am trying to access Appium Inspector on iOS iPhone 16 using MacOS with M1.
Problem : Previously using appium inspector I was able to inspect the elements/locators for iOS on real device as well as simulator.
But after migrating to macOS Sequoia I observed Appium inspector is not getting loaded and observed error 500
Error stack :
Got response with status 500: {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"-[XCUIApplicationProcess waitForQuiescenceIncludingAnimationsIdle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002c7f900"

Encountered internal error running command: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: -[XCUIApplicationProcess waitForQuiescenceIncludingAnimationsIdle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002c7f900

After analysed I saw this is occurring after cmd 'getPageSource'

Matched '/source?format=xml&scope=AppiumAUT' to command name
'getPageSource'

Anyone has observe this kind of behavior and already aware about fix?strong text

Solution :

Check and update the Appium inspector version
This is due to bug introduced in XCUITest Framework. So update your driver
Firstly I checked the installed version using appium driver list --installed
Then update the driver using appium driver update xcuitest
Output :

    ✔ Checking if driver 'xcuitest' is updatable
    ✔ Checking if driver 'xcuitest' needs an update
    ✔ Installing 'xcuitest' using NPM install spec 'appium-xcuitest-driver@7.34.2'
    ✔ Updating driver 'xcuitest' from 7.3.1 to 7.34.2
    ℹ Update report:
    ✔   - driver xcuitest updated: 7.3.1 => 7.34.2


Clean up your chache for WDA & run Appium inspector, you surely get success! Cheers :)

